# How to import a datetime data to sqlite3?

Tags: datetime, csv, import, sqlite

I have a CSV file containing a timestamp in the following format:

```
 Datetime, Outdoor, Indoor
 01/01  01:00:00,24.5,21.3
 01/01  02:00:00,24.3,21.1
 01/01  03:00:00,24.1,21.1
 01/01  04:00:00,24.1,20.9
 01/01  05:00:00,25.,21.
 01/01  06:00:00,26.,21.
 01/01  07:00:00,26.6,20.3
 01/01  08:00:00,28.,21.
 01/01  09:00:00,28.9,21.5
 01/01  10:00:00,29.4,22.1
 01/01  11:00:00,30.,22.
 01/01  12:00:00,29.,23.
 01/01  13:00:00,28.4,22.9
 01/01  14:00:00,27.8,22.7
 01/01  15:00:00,27.3,22.3
 01/01  16:00:00,27.,22.
 01/01  17:00:00,26.,21.
 01/01  18:00:00,26.,21.
 01/01  19:00:00,26.3,21.4
 01/01  20:00:00,26.,21.
 01/01  21:00:00,25.9,21.1
 01/01  22:00:00,25.8,21.3
 01/01  23:00:00,25.6,21.4
 01/01  24:00:00,25.5,21.5
```

That is the datetime format is "%m/%d  %H:%M:%S". How can I import this into sqlite3?

Answer (score 3):

"01/01" isn't a date. If you mean "21.0", output "21.0", not "21.".

Edit your csv file (or better yet, fix the program that outputs that junk) so it looks like this.

```
2011-01-01  01:00:00,24.5,21.3
2011-01-01  02:00:00,24.3,21.1
2011-01-01  03:00:00,24.1,21.1
2011-01-01  04:00:00,24.1,20.9
2011-01-01  05:00:00,25.0,21.0
2011-01-01  06:00:00,26.0,21.0
2011-01-01  07:00:00,26.6,20.3
2011-01-01  08:00:00,28.0,21.0
2011-01-01  09:00:00,28.9,21.5
2011-01-01  10:00:00,29.4,22.1
2011-01-01  11:00:00,30.0,22.0
2011-01-01  12:00:00,29.0,23.0
2011-01-01  13:00:00,28.4,22.9
2011-01-01  14:00:00,27.8,22.7
2011-01-01  15:00:00,27.3,22.3
2011-01-01  16:00:00,27.0,22.0
2011-01-01  17:00:00,26.0,21.0
2011-01-01  18:00:00,26.0,21.0
2011-01-01  19:00:00,26.3,21.4
2011-01-01  20:00:00,26.0,21.0
2011-01-01  21:00:00,25.9,21.1
2011-01-01  22:00:00,25.8,21.3
2011-01-01  23:00:00,25.6,21.4
2011-01-01  24:00:00,25.5,21.5
```

Then set the separator and import the file.

```
sqlite> .separator ','
sqlite> .import filename tablename
```